zsh module command not found
I recently switched from bash to zsh on CentOS 7. I am using oh-my-zsh
I'm encountering an issue where modules cannot be loaded from a script. When I manually load the module in the login shell, it works fine. However, when I incorporate the same command into a test.sh script, I receive an error stating module command not found.
I discovered that sourcing /usr/share/Modules/init/zsh in the script resolves the issue. Nonetheless, if I do not source it, the script fails. I've tried including this source command in both .zshrc and .zsh_profile, but neither approach has been successful.
Is there anything else I should consider doing? Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.
.zshrc
    # Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
    # Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
    # confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
    #if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
    #  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"

#fi

# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

unsetopt nomatch

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
#CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment one of the following lines to change the auto-update behavior
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode disabled  # disable automatic updates
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto      # update automatically without asking
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode reminder  # just remind me to update when it's time

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# You can also set it to another string to have that shown instead of the default red dots.
# e.g. COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="%F{yellow}waiting...%f"
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts in zsh < 5.7.1 (see #5765)
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions zsh-syntax-highlighting web-search you-should-use colored-man-pages dirhistory git colorize cp)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
#[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh




# .bashrc


# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# Add cuda10 binaries to the path
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin/:$PATH

## PULCHARA #######
export PATH=/home/$USER/Downloads/pulchra304/src/:$PATH

# User specific aliases and functions

.bash_profile
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH


Is there an issue sourcing the initialization script inside the script? I imagine that the module init script you source sets up some shell functions.  These are generally not exported to child processes, so if you source the module init script in the interactive shell, your script won't benefit unless it also sources the module init script.

This really should not be necessary; I've been personally using Zsh + oh-my-zsh on CentOS 7, a while ago (when CentOS7 was not yet basically obsolete). Please share your .zshrc and .zsh_profile!

@MarcusMüller I have added the .zshrc, however I do not have a .zsh_profile file.

You said in your question "I've tried including this source command in ... .zsh_profile". If you don't have a .zsh_profile then don't say you do in your question and also tell and show us which *.*profile" (just .profile maybe?) is being executed on login.

@EdMorton Sorry, but I created a .zsh_profile with just that command.  Nothing else.
How can I know which .profile is being executed? I guess the .bash_profile, I have attached the .bash_profile to the question.

The documentation (e.g. man page) for whichever shell you use upon login (zsh or bash or something else) will tell which .*profile file it looks for and where it looks for it in what order upon login. If you're using zsh, it wouldn't expect it to read .bash_profile and vice-versa.
